# Is there a maximum resolution for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I intend to buy an auxiliar monitor, which is 4K and have a max resolution of 2560x1440:
http://accessories.la.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=br&cs=brdhs1&l=pt&sku=210-AMUH

Does ubuntu 16.04 have any max resolution limitations, or will it fill any areas of the screen with black margins (either on the new monitor, or my notebook screen)? Or this depends on my notebook hardware exclusively?

Comment: It depends entirely on your hardware and the quality of the drivers (nvidia / ati / intel / open source) . If you have a problem, you would file a bug report

Comment: You have a 4k monitor currently and want to add a 2560x1440 monitor? It depends on your hardware (including the cables). There will be no letterboxing of any monitors, though. As long as your hardware supports it, the monitors should all be able to display at their native resolutions. There are options for scaling when DPI doesn't match and such, though.

Comment: Actually the new monitor goes up to 2560x1440. The current notebook screen is lower than that. Can't say exactly because I'm not at home right now.